# Rotating several planes on their x axis by the same angle

Tags: objects, transforms

I created 5 squares from planes.

I placed four of them around the fifth, forming a cross.

The question is: how can I rotate the four squares along their respective axes **at the same time** so that they start forming the sides of a box around the fifth square?

See picture...

This is only an example. In reality, I want to do that with pentagons and rotate the now five pentagons surrounding the central one so that they form a "vase", that is when the vertices of adjacent pentagons come to touch each other.

[image: Here on the right, I did it by hand].

Thank you @Rick T for the hint about uploading a blend file...
Here it comes!

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: Hello, have you thought about parenting to some bones or empties? Then you could just rotate one and the other would rotate as well with some constraints

Comment: @moonboots that sounds great, and, because I am rather of a beginner, could you expand a little on the procedure or give links to some tutorials I could get inspiration from. I have never used bones and rigging...

Comment: You should find several tutorials on this topic, if they don't properly answer don't hesitate to explain where you're struggling: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+rigging+a+box

Comment: @moonboots Well, thanks a lot: the first video I checked, "How to rig opening a box," seems to be doing precisely what I am looking for!

Answer (score 1):

First thing we'll do in your file is enable the display of axes on your objects:

[image]

We can see that the objects do not have consistent axes relative to their geometry.  We can adjust those to eye by enabling "affect only origins" in sidebar/tool and then rotating each.  We'll rotate each to match the origins displayed on the active element above, with X being the desired rotation axis:

[image]

We'll change our pivot point to individual origins and our orientation to local, and disable "affect only origins".  Now we can select all of the objects we wish to rotate and r x to rotate each in its individual X axis, about each's individual origin, at the same time:

[image]

You may notice that the rotation isn't *perfect*.  That's because I aligned the axes to eye rather than being very precise.  While it is possible to create precise local axes, it is usually more difficult than using bones rather than objects to do the transformations, where we can just snap our bones heads/tails to cursors (and recalculate roll to cursors), cursors that we can snap to geometry.  I would personally use bones (armatures) for this purpose, but you might not be ready for that yet, I don't know.

Comment: Thank you so much. The method you provided me, because it is so basic, has taught me so much I can use in many other situation. Now I have full control of how to rotate these hexagons!

And I will also check out what rigging can do for me...